# Creating a UIButton that changes with my repopulating UICollectionView Carousel, also adding in gifs to replace current images

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, animated-gif

So Im pretty new to the swift language and not well versed in its structure, However I have managed to design a collection view to scroll horizontally through repopulating images. Ideally what I would like to do is be able to select that image and bring it to another screen to proceed with the application. I know I need to repopulate the button each time we repopulate the collection cell, however being novice I am currently failing at doing so. Any suggestions to make this work would be fantastic. Also any directions into incorporating gifs into the collection view instead of an image would also be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some example code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: are you using storyboard? are the images stored locally or pulled from the internet? Are you using gif because you want an the image to animate?

Comment: Ive made some alterations to the code in the link, but all the files are there to view and play with, Ive done some slight modifications, but here is the link

Comment: https://github.com/ductrongtran/CarouselCollectionView/blob/master/Interests/HomeViewController.swift

Comment: the code works fine, Im just not sure how to add in a button that Populates the correct text whilst sending it to a new view controller based on what the user chooses